# swift 3 filter multiple "not equals to" conditions

Tags: arrays, swift3

In Swift 3 I am filtering and creating an array as so (while iterating through an existing array) :

```
self.uniqueAddresses = self.uniqueAddresses.filter { $0.lat != thisUniqueAddress.lat) && $0.lng != thisUniqueAddress.lng }
```

I want to exclude from my new array only those existing objects that match BOTH conditions. That means if an object's lat is like mine AND its lng is ALSO like mine THEN I don't want it in my new array. However if one of them matches it's no problem and it may be included. I'm using the && operator to give me both conditions together, however even if only one of the conditions is true it also matches my conditions, and hence is not being included in my new array which is not what I want. I've tried grouping them together with parentheses but I'm getting the same results.

Comment: actually, I didn't express myself properly. the new array should not contain an object that matches both my lat and my lng. Which is why I'm writing "!= lat" and "!= ing" because if they are the same than what I already have I don't want it. Right now what's happening is that even if one is the same it is also not being included because it considers that a match

Comment: I edited my question to make it a little clearer

Comment: Thanks. The correct logic was posted in the answer by @Robert

Comment: I meant "if an object's lat is like mine but its lang is not like mine" (or vice versa) I DO want to include it in the new array

Comment: Edited:  "if an object's lat is like mine AND its lng is ALSO like mine THEN I don't want it in my new array." It should have read the opposite: " if an object's lat is like mine AND its lng is ALSO like mine THEN I don't want it in my new array." The new edit reflects this change. Robert's answer appears to work fine now because if anything is a mismatch I want to include it in the new array. So now I'm getting the result I want.  One part mismatched: included. Both parts mismatched: included. Both parts matched: NOT included.

Comment: Right, okay then – Robert's answer is indeed correct :) Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a boolean logic issue. You want the address to be in the output array if either the latitude is unique OR the longitude is unique, so you need an `or` operator where you currently have `and`:

```
self.uniqueAddresses = self.uniqueAddresses.filter { $0.lat != thisUniqueAddress.lat || $0.lng != thisUniqueAddress.lng }
```

Here's test code to try in your playground:

```
let thisUniqueAddress = (lat: 0, lng: 0)
var uniqueAddresses:[(lat:Int,lng:Int)] = [(lat: 0, lng: 0),
                                 (lat: 0, lng: 1),
                                 (lat: 1, lng: 0),
                                 (lat: 1, lng: 1)]
uniqueAddresses = uniqueAddresses.filter {$0.lat != thisUniqueAddress.lat || $0.lng != thisUniqueAddress.lng}
print(uniqueAddresses)
```

It outputs `[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]`, omitting the one point `(0, 0)` that matches on both `.lat` and `.lng`.

Comment: Don't know why, but the logic is somehow different than how my brain would process it somehow..... thanks, though. This is exactly what I was looking for and it works

Comment: @ChaimFriedman I know! It looked right to me the way you had it. I had to take out all the shorthand and write a separate filter function to see that it didn't do what I thought it did.